# Execute BASH script from SQL script under ASSERT

Tags: sql, bash, assert

The goal is to execute a script *hi.sh* after an assertion in SQL script.

*hi.sh* contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello World'
```

I'm trying to execute *hi.sh* within DO:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   ASSERT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'), '"Public" schema is empty';
   \! ./hi.sh
END$$;
```

It should raise error '"Public" schema is empty' and not execute *hi.sh* but once there are entries in public schema, *hi.sh* must be executed.

Running the sql script raises error:

```
psql:assert.sql:5: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 4:    \! ./hi.sh
           ^
```

However, it will execute shell script once '\!' line is outside DO, like this:

```
\! ./hi.sh
```

How can we create a simple SQL script for executing *hi.sh* based on assertion?

Comment: `\!` is not SQL! It's a client command!

Comment: Yes, scripts are executed with: psql -d postgres - f script.sql

Comment: I think it's a ***wrong good idea*** to run script from sql client. You'd better create a script that run psql as backgrounded task, interact with them and run subshell when needed. See my function *newSqlConnector* in [my *shell_connector.sh*](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh.txt), and [my answer to *How do I set a variable to the output of a command*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236640/1765658).

Comment: Thanks, I have solved like so before, was looking for a simplified solution. So the answer is that it is not possible to execute bash scripts with psql client.

Comment: Yes, it is! But in the other way! Have a look at my *shell connector*! Install `sqlite3` then run this as a *demo*. Look into script to find correct syntax for addressing `psql`, Your script had to *source* them, inititate `newSqlConnector`, then interaction with `psql` is ready.

Comment: ... And yes, I think the way you previously use is still possible, but discouraged...